# Is the tense in the sentence correct?

Tags: grammaticality, tenses

The sentence is

> I bought a bottle of milk on Friday night, and I found that it had gone sour the following morning.

I think the past perfect tense is weird with "the following morning."
Am I right?

Comment: Sounds correct, but wordy.  Better:  I bought a bottle of milk Friday night; the next morning it was sour.  (14 words vs. 20 words)

Answer (score 2):

This is ordinary and correct.

The clauses concerning purchase and finding are consecutive narrative pasts.

The clause with past perfect *had gone sour* is subordinate to the second of those clauses only, and is unaffected by the first:

> On the following morning I found that it had gone sour [at some earlier time during the night].

Answer (score 0):

It does sound weird to me. I suggest that you swap the subordinate clause with the main clause to make the sentence easier to understand:

> I bought a bottle of milk on Friday night, and the following morning I
>   found that it had gone sour.